# "Bake" curve modifier to use mesh & animation in Unreal Engine

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, .fbx

**Edit adressing duplicate..below the "Old" question**

I'm currently trying to create text animations in Blender which I later want to use in the Unreal Engine.

As the text should not just follow a path but rather also bend its shape, I used a curve modifier to achieve this effect.

It all looks great in Blender. The Text Mesh is following the curve, bending and moving, but exporting it results in losing the animation on the curve.

Is there a way to bake the animation (bending and movement of the mesh) so I can use it outside of Blender?
Or should I consider another solution?

Thanks in advance!
Daniel

Edit: 
As this was marked a duplicate - 
The problem isn't that I can't bake an animation using the follow path constraint..
The problem is that I am not able to get the bending **and** movement baked at the same time using the **curve modifier** .

I'm animating the X-Value of the text mesh to let it follow and bend along the spline. Exporting it results in a bent text moving along the x-axis. 
The same happens when I'm applying the modifier. 
So how can I apply it and or export it, keeping the movement and bending?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't helping as I don't want the text to just follow a path..but also bend to it. This doesn't seem to bake / export correctly.
See the help..any help would be appreciated and removing the marked answered as this isn't the case. 

@Ray-Mairlot

Comment: Firstly, spaces should be removed from usernames otherwise people don't get notified, e.g. "@RayMairlot". Secondly, now that you have added more information, people with enough reputation have the opportunity to vote to re-open it.

Comment: Note that it takes several people to vote for a question to be re-opened, not just me. I suggest having a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/help which may answer several questions you have as to how things work on the site.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for reopening the question! (Also for you response and explanation on twitter :-) )